# Azure Load Balancer Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure Load Balancer,
I have gone into the Load Balancer resource, Diagnostics logs and ticked 'Send to Log Analytics' and set to my Azure Log Analytics OMS Workspace.

But when I go into the Log Analytics and run:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus" and TimeGenerated  > ago(3d)
| project ResourceGroup, Resource, TimeGenerated, port_d, totalDipCount_d, dipDownCount_d, healthPercentage_d
```

I don't get any results, can anyone help my understand how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the Azure Diagnostics table in Log Analytics has reached [the max 500](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/resource-logs-collect-workspace)  columns.

Can Run the following query to confirm:

```
AzureDiagnostics
|  getschema
| summarize AggregatedValue = count(ColumnName)
```